# How to build a line graph from two data sets in one table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having an issue with Excel to which I can't find an accurate solution online.

I have this table:

```
PERSON   |  DATE  |   SIZE
==========================
Matt     |  1-10  |   90.1
Jane     |  1-10  |   71.3
Matt     |  1-11  |   90.0  
Jane     |  1-11  |   71.0
Matt     |  1-12  |   89.6
Jane     |  1-13  |   70.2
```

And so on...

The thing is that this is the best solution for inputting this kind of data. I can't have two different tables, one for each person involved, because more people will probably be involved later on, and they all should be included in the same table.

As you can see, the idea is to monitor their weights. And this would be better achieved visually by a line graph that can tell each person what their progress is.

To this end, I would like to set up one graph that shows each person's progress individually as a different line. Like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there was any way of having Excel automatically build this line graph using this table but ordering values according to *if cell X has value...*.

Not being able to find that, I also tried to set up an *invisible* table that would gather each set in its own column. For that, I was thinking of using an IF statement but I can't seem to find a way of getting that to populate a separate table, row by row, with the data from the original table. On the Internet I can only find how to add up all the values in a certain cell if another certain cell has X value.

I was wondering if anyone out there could give me a hand with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just a standard line graph.  When I entered your table in a sheet and created a line graph, the chart you want was created by default.

Comment: @jbarker2160, thanks for the response. I'm not getting that, however. When I try and make a graph out of my table it puts together all of the data. As if Matt and Jane's weights were of the same series. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a pivot table and pivot chart to accomplish this.

1. Insert a pivot table, select your entire data range (including headers).
2. Select Person, Date, and Size in the field list.
3. Under pivot table options select pivot chart and choose your desired chart type.
4. Move Person to Legend Fields, Date to Axis Fields, and Size to Values.
5. Right click the pivot table and go to PivotTable Options
6. Under "For empty cells show: " write N/A (this will let Excel ignore missing dates)

[Here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/a-better-way-to-show-empty-values-in-a-pivot-table/) is an example of the blank values.

Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Excellent idea! Not sure if it's the only way to manage this but it surely works. However, I don't seem to be able to config the pivot chart as freely as I would a normal chart. Say, the range of data on an axis and the interval. I can't seem to edit this. The pivot graph just gives me a default set with a rather big interval that doesn't allow me to focus on specific numbers. Note I'm setting sizes to decimal places for very specific measurement. Of course, I don't expect decimal places but at least integers. Right now, the interval is fixed on jumping by ten #s.

Comment: What you can do for that is select the axis on the left. Right click and choose Format Axis and then if you set Minimum to fixed you can specify the lowest number on the scale. By setting Major unit to fixed you can specify what the axis increments by.

Comment: Oh, found it! :( Dumb me... I don't know why I was trying to get this by formatting the gridlines! That was a terrible lapsus! Thanks for the excellent help! I'm voting this as the answer because it surely does solve the issue!